# I am the admin but not the owner. How do I become the owner

Tags: permissions

I try to save `/etc/default/grub` after making edits, but I don't have permission and only the owner can change permissions. How do I become the owner?

Comment: Why do you want to change the permissions and owner, you are inviting trouble.

Comment: Is it not "root/root"?

Comment: I wouldn't change the permissions. Just edit it as root using `sudo` (su is superuser aka administrator): `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`.

Comment: So what is the issue if you are using sudo?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to edit system files is to open them in a text editor with `root` permisions.

So:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

or as [Radu Rădeanu](https://askubuntu.com/users/147044/radu-rdeanu) suggested:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

will work perfectly.

You might want to make a backup copy in case you mess up:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup
```

To restore:

```
sudo rm /etc/default/grub
sudo mv /etc/default/grub.backup /etc/default/grub
```

It's not a good idea to change ownership of system files.

Comment: [Never use `sudo gedit [...]`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I guess `nano` is the best choice.

Comment: `sudo nano`, `sudo -H gedit`, `gksu gedit`, a.o.